# When updating database I get a EntityValidationError

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-update, httphandler

I'm trying to get the logged in user to edit his profile. For now I decided to use a satic userID *(since using the sessions usedID was also giving me errors)*. Now when I run the code it goes through all the lines but at the end it gives me this error "EntityValidationErrors".

I just want the code to update the current UserID's Bio, Sex, and preferred sex

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FillProfile(tblUser user)
{
        using (TrinityEntities db = new TrinityEntities())
        {
            var id = Session["userID"];
            user.Id = 1018; //Convert.ToInt32(id);

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\Periode 2\Persoonlijk\Trinity\Trinity\Trinity\App_Data\Trinity.mdf; Integrated Security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True; Connect Timeout = 30; Application Name = EntityFramework");

            conn.Open();

            string Query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, Age FROM tblUser WHERE Id='" + user.Id + "'";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                { 
                    user.FirstName = reader[0] as string;
                    user.LastName = reader[1] as string;
                    user.Email = reader[2] as string;
                    user.Password = reader[3] as string;
                    string Sage = reader[4] as string;
                    user.Age = Convert.ToInt32(Sage);
                    break;
                }

                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            conn.Close();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
}
```

View:

```
@model Trinity.Models.tblUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profile";

    // prevent login by alterring adress
    if (Session["userID"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Login/Index");
    }
}

<h2>Let's fill you profile!</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("FillProfile", "Profile", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sex, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sex,
            new List<SelectListItem> {
                  new SelectListItem { Value = "Male" , Text = "Male" },
                  new SelectListItem { Value = "Female" , Text = "Female" },
               },
            new {@class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sex, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Preffered, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Preffered,
            new List<SelectListItem> {
                  new SelectListItem { Value = "Female" , Text = "Female" },
                  new SelectListItem { Value = "Male" , Text = "Male" },
                  new SelectListItem { Value = "Both" , Text = "Both" }
               },
            new {@class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Preffered, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BIO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.BIO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BIO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <label class="label-success">@ViewBag.SuccessMessage</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <label class="label-warning">@ViewBag.AlreadyRegisteredMessage</label>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Model classes:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Trinity.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class tblUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[^\W\d_]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters allowed in your name")]

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[^\W\d_]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters allowed in your name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string BIO { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("E-Mail")]
        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect E-mail Format")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W]).*$", ErrorMessage = "Password must be 8 characters, contain at least 1 digit and one special character")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage ="Passwords are not the same")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Age")]
        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Preferred { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide User model class

Comment: Added the database model class!